# CFString memory leak when NSManagedObjectContext is updated

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, memory-leaks, instruments

Once a minute I am running an update to my sqlite database using core data, by making a web request, parsing that request, and updating objects on my managed object context.
The JSON data returned from the webserver is stored in an NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

I initialize an NSOperation instance with the dictionary stored as a member. The operation loops through the dictionary and update a NSManagedObjectContext, for example:

```
    for (NSDictionary *item in self.dictionary) {
          NSManagedObject *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
          [newItem setValue:item[@"customerName"] forKey:@"contact_firstname"];
    }
    [self.context save:&error];
```

Looking at the instruments panel, I see that each update leaves few unreleased CFString objects:

[image]

The difference between the released and unreleased CFStrings can be shown by the refcount trace of each:

**Released**
[image]

**Unreleased:**
[image]

The retain (+1) made by `[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _newAllPropertiesWithRelationshipFaultsIntact__]` prevents this object from being released. Since every update I delete all objects from the MSManagedObjectContext, I don't see any reason why these CFStrings should not be released.

What is the purpose of _newAllPropertiesWithRelationshipFaultsIntact__, and why does it retain some of my CFStrings?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

`NSManagedObjectContext` will keep all changes made to all the objects it manages, even after you call `save:`. This might be the issue here, to check that you can call `reset` after you call `save:`. `reset` will simply erase all unsaved changes that has made to the `moc` since the time it started from the CoreData DB.

```
[self.context save:&error];
[self.context reset];
```